# Raspberry Pi 3 UART with ATmega328p

Tags: gpio, serial

I'm trying to send data from ATmega328p to Raspberry Pi 3 with UART using Pis gpios.

The problem is Pi does not seem to be getting any data from the microcontroller.

Here is how I wired the microcontroller to Pi:

- ATmega328p **VCC** to Raspberry Pi **5 volt pin**. *changed to 3.3 volt pin*
- ATmega328p **GND** to Raspberry Pi **ground pin**.
- ATmega328p **RESET** to Raspberry Pi **GPIO #12**.
- ATmega328p **SCK** to Raspberry Pi **GPIO #24**.
- ATmega328p **MOSI** to Raspberry Pi **GPIO #23**.
- ATmega328p **MISO** to Raspberry Pi **GPIO #18**.
- ATmega328p **TXD** to Raspberry Pi **RX pin**.
- ATmega328p **RXD** to Raspberry Pi **TX pin**.

Here is the C code for microcontroller:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#define BAUD 9600UL
#define BRC ((F_CPU/16/BAUD)-1)

int main(void){ 
 UBRR0H =(BRC >> 8);
 UBRR0L = BRC;

 UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0);
 UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);

 while(1){
  UDR0 = '8';
  _delay_ms(1000);

 }
 return 0;
}
```

And the python 2.7 script for Pi:

```
import serial


port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate = 9600, timeout=5)

port.flush()

while True:

    rcv = port.read(10)

    print "AVR is sending" + rcv
```

With `sudo raspi-config` I have enabled serial port hardware and made login shell to be **not** accessible over serial.

**EDIT**

I've tested if UART pins are any functional by hooking Pi pin 8(TX) to pin 10(RX) and running a python script which I copied from this tutorial http://www.elinux.org/Serial_port_programming .

Here is the script itself:

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)

while True:
    port.write("\r\nSay something:")
    rcv = port.read(10)
    port.write("\r\nYou sent:" + repr(rcv))
```

The script is running but nothing is appearing on the screen. Seems like the script is unable to write to the port.

I've also double checked that serial is enabled in hardware and serial console is disabled.

In `/boot/config.txt` `enable_uart=1` is set.

Comment: Do you have any debugging tools available such as an oscilloscope to verify if any data is being sent from the AVR's Tx pin? Your AVR code looks the same as my UART library except I have a check to ensure the Transmit buffer is ready to receive new data before moving the data into UDR0 `while(!( UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));`

Comment: The GPIO pins of the Pi are not 5V tolerant you risk destroying the pin or your entire Pi.

Comment: I used `ISR(USART_TX_vect)` to light up an LED when transmission is complete. It appears that microcontroller does transmit the bytes.

Answer (score 2):

With a 1MHz clock speed on the AVR your selected baud rate will not work because the actual baud rate after integer clock division will be at too much of an error compared to your desired baud rate. It will still transmit but your receiver will not recognise it.

It is possible to use 9600 but you need to write a 1 to `U2X0` in `UCSR0A`, you will then need to do `BRC*2` as well.

See this site for a useful [AVR baud rate calculator](http://wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php).

## Edit - Configuring the Serial Port

Dug this out  from some of my old documentation as well.

From command line type:

`$sudo raspi-config`

Go to *Advanced Options > Serial interface* and select yes to enable, exit settings menu and reboot if prompted.

Type:

`$sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt`

Remove the part that reads:

> console=serial0,115200

Then save and exit.

Now use a terminal program such as screen or minicom to try and talk to the Pi.

Comment: I've changed the BAUD to 4800, still no success... I'm guessing that UART pins on Pi are simply dead, nevertheless `./pintest` shows that all pins are ok.

Comment: There is a lot of protection built into the Pi to prevent you from killing it when experimenting so I highly doubt 5V has killed it. It sounds like it is a problem with the way you have set up your serial port on the Pi. Could you please follow this [guide](https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/) which also gives some useful info on the port. And then use a terminal program, such as minicom, to talk to the AVR. This will verify if you have comms or if there is a problem with your python script.

Comment: See my edit in the answer before you try the guide I linked in the previous comment

Comment: Yes ! It did work ! In the guide you recommended I read that AMA0 port is mainly used for Bluetooth on Rpi 3 so I configured minicom to listen to S0 port and hooked Pis Rx pin to ATmegas TX and it did transmit ! However, when run a python script to write and receive it doesn't work, maybe it's just something wrong withe the script itself. I haven't tested the to transmit from Pi yet but I'm glad that receiving works now ! Thank you very much pfl for provided help !

Comment: Sounds obvious but did you definitely change the line `port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)` to use  `/dev/ttyS0`? and are you running the script as sudo?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I changed it to `/dev/ttyS0` and ran it with sudo. The script is running but does not show anything. And that's only true for a script which sends and reads, but the script which does reading only works fine.